# hasura cron trigger getting timed out before the specified time

Tags: cron, hasura

I've a setup a cron job in hasura and specified a timeout of 18000 seconds with 2 retries if fails but I can see the cron job is retrying after 5 or 6 minutes and the log says

```
{
    "data": {
        "message": "stream timeout"
    },
    "type": "client_error",
    "version": "1"
}
```

This is causing the cron job to run multiple times.